# How can I make from 'Untracked' to 'Changed to be commited.'

Tags: git

I'm starting Putty for the first time. When I've typed 'git status' why can't I make changes committed? (although everything is up-to-date)

```
    $ cd lab1
    $ ls
    $ vim list.c
    $ cat list.c
    $ git status
    $ git add list.c (And after typing this code, I've typed one more time because it didn't work!)

    $ git status
    On branch master
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

    Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .list.c.swo
    .list.c.swp

    nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

    $ git add list.c
    `On branch master
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

    Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .list.c.swo
    .list.c.swp

    nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

> > not changing

I hope that after I typed 
        $ git status
        On branch master
        Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'
        Changes to be committed:~~
               new file: list.c

```
    $ cd lab1
    $  ls
    $ vim list.c
    $ cat list.c
    $ git status
    $ git add list.c
```

(And after typing this code, I've typed one more time because it didn't work!)

```
    $ git status
    'On branch master
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

    Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .list.c.swo
    .list.c.swp

    nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

    $ git add list.c
    `On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

    Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .list.c.swo
    .list.c.swp

    nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

But not changing

I hope that after I typed $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'
Changes to be committed:~~
               new file: list.c

Comment: The file isn't named `list.c`, it's named `.list.c.swo`, this sounds to me like a temporary file so I'm not sure you *want* to add it, but either way, if you actually want to add those files you have to spell their names out correctly or use some form of wildcard.

Comment: `.swp` and `.swo` are temporary files for the `vim` editor; you do not normally want these in any Git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%c3%a5gs%c3%a6ther-karlsen) said, you added `list.c` and not `.list.c.swo`.

Note that these are hidden files (in UNIX-like environments hidden files start with `.`.).
If you still want to add these files, you can do `git add .list.c.swo` and `git add .list.c.swo` or `git add .list.c.sw*` or `git add .` (if you want to add everything)

But these seem to be automatically generated files that you may not want to have in your repository. I recommand you to add them to your .gitignore

You can e.g. add the following to lines to the `.gitignore`:

```
*.swo
*.swp
```

If those 2 lines are in a file `.gitignore` in the root of your repository, git will ignore every file that ends with `.swo` or `.swp`.

You can also ignore all (hidden) files (except `.gitignore`) that start with `.`:

```
.*
!.gitignore
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `git add .` this one will add all files which are not added. Then you can commit and push

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem. In fact, he already tried this.